# LARAVEL-8, BOOTSTRAP-5. Im using an external CSS file for main layout for header and sidebar and when i @extends, the content format is distorted

Tags: html, css, laravel-8, laravel-blade, bootstrap-5

**Main layout CSS file for the header and sidebar:**

`<link href="{{ asset('app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

*Note: External app.css file is under public route

**Content: Homepage**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/TRform.css">
```

*Note: This is the CSS for the content

For the content.blade.php file, my code:

```
@extends('Layout')

@section('content')

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/TRform.css">
{html for content here}


@endsection
```

Problem:
-I am currently using the bootstrap header and sidebar but i created an external `app.css` file
to include my own designs too. However, when i tried to `@extends` to the content with another css:`TPform.css` file, the `app.css` file overwrites the TPform.css file although i inserted the `TPform.css` at the bottom of the  tag. Now, my TPform design is not working but the header and sidebar design is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If it is happening like that I am 100% sure either you are not fetching your stylesheets properly or you just didn't design your layout properly before executing it.